# Flow with Finish location

Tags: flow

I am very new to visual flows. I want to create a visual flow to assign for a login flow. The flow does not need  any user interaction components. The flow should direct to a specific URL depending on a Boolean value on user object. I need a two visual flows : each directs to different URL depending on the TRUE or False value on the Boolean field.
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

You can set the finish location in the flow itself if you cannot use different profiles to determine which finish location to use.

From the [Developer Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Login-Flows) on login flows

> There are also the following output attributes that can be set in the flow itself: LoginFlow_FinishLocation - String type. Setting this
> variable will determine where to send the user when the flow
> completes.
>
> LoginFlow_ForceLogout - Boolean type. Setting this variable to true
> immediately logs the user out.

So you should just be able to use a Decision within the flow based on the field to set the LoginFlow_FinishLocation.